# Creating new sheet in excel and writing data with openpyxl

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, openpyxl

I have already existing excel file and at the beginning in my code i import data from first sheet.

Now i cant write points from two variables `(xw, yw)` into new sheet in excel to two colmuns (A1-A[Q] and B1-B[Q]).

`xw` and `yw` are arrays consisting of float numbers (example: 1.223, 2.434 etc.).

```py
Q = len(xw)
wb.create_sheet('Points')
sheet2 = wb.get_sheet_by_name('Points')
for q in range(1,Q):
    sheet2["A[q]"]=xw[q]
    sheet2["B[q]"]=yw[q]
wb.save('PARAMS.xlsx')
```

**EDIT:**

I want to fill third column with zeros (C1-CQ). My code is below, but its start from C2, not C1. I did `sheet2[f"C{1}"]=0` but it looks bad. What is the solution?

```py
Q = len(xw)
zw= np.zeros(Q)
sheet2 = wb.create_sheet('Points')
sheet2[f"A{1}"]=0
sheet2[f"B{1}"]=T_r
sheet2[f"C{1}"]=0
for i, row in enumerate(sheet2.iter_rows(min_row=2, max_col=3, max_row=Q+1)):
    row[0].value = xw[i]
    row[1].value = yw[i]
    row[2].value = zw[i]
wb.save('PARAMS.xlsx')
```

Comment: Use `ws.cell(row=q, column=1)` for programmatic access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to acces literally the cell `"A[q]"` which of course does not exist. Change it to `f"A{q}"` (The same to `B` of course).

Also, `openpyxl` uses 1-based indexing so it means you will skip your first elements from the lists. Therefore you should do:

```py
for q in range(Q):
    sheet2[f"A{q+1}"] = xw[q]
    sheet2[f"B{q+1}"] = yw[q]
```

Alternatively, you could use the API of `openpyxl` to access the cells using [`iter_rows`](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial.html#accessing-many-cells) and [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate):

```py
for i, row in enumerate(sheet2.iter_rows(min_row=1, max_col=2, max_row=Q)):
    row[0].value = xw[i]
    row[1].value = yw[i]
```

---

Notice that `create_sheet` also **returns** the sheet created so you can simply do:

```
sheet2 = wb.create_sheet('Points')
```

Comment: i want to start from first element of xw array but ```for q in range(1,Q)``` starts from second element. When i type ```for q in range(Q)``` there is error  ```self[key].value = value``` ```AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'value'```

Comment: Please look at my EDIT

Comment: It is not necessary to do `f"A{1}"` if you simply want to put the character 1... the notation `{}` is used to convert variables to strings. If you simply want the first cell write `A1`, `B1` and so on... Also, try not to mix questions. If some answer solved your original problem, accept it. And if you are encountering new difficulties, open a new question. Mixing in edits of completely new questions lead to a messy post

Answer (score 0):

Where possible try and and avoid your own counters. openpyxl uses 1-based indexing for rows and columns so it can be confusing to mix this with Python's standard 0-based indexing. You can usually avoid this by looping directly over iterables like lists and arrays.

```
for idx, a, b in enumerate(zip(xw, yw), 1):
   ws.cell(row=idx, column=1, value=a)
   ws.cell(row_idx, column=2, value=b)
```